# check file md5 before upload start

Tags: file-upload, promise, fine-uploader

I use [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) for uploading multiple files to a server.

I want to send the MD5 hash of each file to the server before upload and if a file exists on the server, the file uploading be abandoned.

I use the "sparkMD5" MD5 library along with Fine Uploader's `setParams` method to add the MD5 hash as parameter for each file.

My problem - calculating the MD5 of some files may take several seconds. I need to wait until the MD5 of the file has been calculated and sent to server.
I return a promise but it is blocking file from being added to file list (after the user select the file).

```
onSubmit: function(id){
    var file = this.getFile(id), promise = new qq.Promise();
    calculate_md5_then_check_with_server_for_duplication(id, file);
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader needs a resolved value from the `onSubmit` handler in order to properly handle the file. By default, the file will be automatically uploaded after this callback is completed. It is also possible that the result of the handler would prevent the file from being accepted. So flashing the file initially, only to have it removed may be a bit jarring.  This is why the file does not appear in the UI until your promise has been successfully resolved.

If you'd like to give the user some indication as to the progress of the MD5 calculation, you can certainly do that using whatever UI fits your application best.